# Document or Text Clustering using EM algorithm for GMM, how to do?

Tags: java, algorithm, nlp, cluster-analysis

I am trying to make a project of Document Clustering (in Java). There can be maximum 1 million documents and I want to make unsupervised cluster. To do, I am trying to implement EM algorithm with Gaussian Mixture Model.

But, I am not sure how to make the document vector.

I am thinking something like this, first I will calculate TF/IDF for each word in the document(after removing stop words and stemming done).

Then I will normalize each vector. At this stage, the question arises, how shall I represent a vector by a point? Is it possible?

I have learned about EM algorithm from this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iQoXFmbXRJA) video where 1-D points are used for GMM and to be used in EM.

Can any one explain how to convert a vector in a 1-D point to implement EM for GMM?

If my approach is wrong, can you explain how to do the whole thing in simple words? Sorry for my long question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to be clustering that many documents, you might consider K-Medoids as well, it creates the initial centroids using randomization (basically). As for representing the vectors as a point, In my experience that is really sketchy. What I have done in the past is store term vectors in a SortedMap, remove irrelevant terms however you want, normalize the vectors into sparse representations, then you can use something like Cosine Similarity, or Euclidean distance (inverted) to gauge similarity. I have used JavaML, Weka, and rolled my own unsupervised clustering. The KMedoids in JavaML is pretty good, you will have to reduce your vectors to double[] data structures (normalized of course) and use their dataset object.
HTH

Comment: Thanks Mark. I must have to use EM with GMM :( no way! To be specific, I need a solution for "Document Clustering using EM with GMM". Can you suggest any link(s)? It can be in any language, preferably in Java.

Comment: Basically, I am having trouble to convert document's bag of words into vector. I am not getting in which form of vector should I convert. Is it should be TF-IDF conversion of each word? or just frequency count? After conversion, how should I represent a vector as a single point. Should I take just mean of all the word values (in their TF-IDF values) or is there any other thing to do? Should I convert the vector into normalized form or not?

Comment: I have used just a term frequency vector mainly... but if you are trying to turn a sparse vector into a scalar value, I'm not sure how to reliably do that.

Comment: Will it be a sparse vector? I will just keep the TF-IDF values instead of each word and then I will normalize each vector. Normalization will give different types of values (not only 0 or 1). So, will it be a sparse vector? I also can use term frequency (TF), but that doesn't always guarantee a word to be considered as a keyword.

Comment: I think of it as sparse because when you compare the vectors, not every document will have a value for every word.. so the pairwise comparison is done on sparse vectors. if docA has a,b,c and docB has a,b,d, then c  = 0 in docb and d = 0 in docA. Perhaps i've done it the hard way, but you first have to sort the words into abcd, then generate two vectors based on the normed abcd structure, then compare them (using some vector similarity measure). HTH

Answer (score 0):

I would start with something simpler than EM for GMM. If you know the number of clusters in advance, use K-Means. Otherwise, use Mean Shift.

If you must learn a GMM, then note that it can work with an N-D feature vector. If you must must reduce the features to a single dimension, you can use PCA (or some other data dimensionality reduction) algorithm  to do that.

In any case, you can find implementations of these algorithms on the net and don't have to implement them yourself, which would slow down your project.

Comment: Thanks Victor. I searched internet for such solution, but couldn't find. Specifically, I need a solution for "Document Clustering using EM with GMM". Can you suggest any link(s)? It can be in any language, preferably in Java. Thanks again!

Comment: Basically, I am having trouble to convert document's bag of words into vector. I am not getting in which form of vector should I convert. Is it should be TF-IDF conversion of each word? or just frequency count? After conversion, how should I represent a vector as a sigle point. Should I take just mean of all the word values (in their TF-IDF values) or is there any other thing to do? Should I convert the vector into normalized form or not?